# Converting DateTime throws SqlDateTime overflow

Tags: c#, datetime

Currently I've a string with a date and time. When I show the string it looks like:

> 2015-06-16 09:17:28 PM

But when I try to put it into the database it's telling me:

> Additional information: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753
>   12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

I've to convert the string. So there is now other way!

What's the right way to do this? Obviously the value in database is datetime.

This is my code (I've put it together actually it's from multiple classes):

```
    string time = date + " " + txtTime.Text;
    DateTime temp = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
    String query ="insert into reserveringen (reserveringId,klantId,medewerkerId,aantalPersonen,begintijd,eindtijd)values(@reserveringId,@klantId,@medewerkerId,@aantalPersonen,@begintijd,@eindtijd)";
    SqlCommand comm = sqlCrud.returnSqlCommand(query);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("begintijd",temp);
```

I already googled a lot.... but nothing works.

Thanks

Comment: Try `DateTime temp = DateTime.Parse(time);`.

Comment: or `DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")`. I think you might need to specify the culture for `ParseExact` too

Comment: I don't know the language... but could it be `eindtijd` that is the problem, and not `begintijd`?  We don't see what you're specifying for that value. (I'm basing the question on the suffix assuming they both mean date :P)

Comment: When you do `AddWithValue`, if you replace `temp` with `DateTime.Now` just as a test.  Does that work?

Comment: You can and should debug `temp`. Also, I'm not sure if those params work without the `@`.

Comment: also... shouldn't *all* of the values you're inserting be parameters?  Where else would the values come from?  from your statement it only looks like one value in your statement is a parameter - `@reserveringId`.

Comment: @Kritner of course my fold. In my code this is right. I'm trying the answers.

Comment: @Kritner it's dutch :)

Comment: Is `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("begintijd",temp);` exactly what you have? If so try `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begintijd",temp);`. (Make sure all of the `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue` statements have @ as the first character of the column name.)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. After all the searching the only thing I had to add was  DateTime temp = DateTime.Parse(time);  thanks @EBrown

Comment: Do note that that uses the 'default' culture, it could fail on with other PC settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Convert.ToDateTime` like that. You should use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`.

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Since `DateTime.Parse(temp)` worked for you, you can leave it as that.

### Edit:

The difference between the two methods is **very** important in this situation.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(s)
```

This method will call `DateTime.Parse` internally with the following parameters:

```
DateTime.Parse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Now, `DateTime.Parse(s)` does something a little different:

```
DateTime.Parse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

The difference is the `DateTimeStyles` flag. This flag **completely** changes the output. The `Convert.ToDateTime(s)` was likely returning a `DateTime.MinValue` object, which is what it does when it encounters a `null` string. (I can only guess without spending more time on research, but that result makes sense, as `DateTime.MinValue` is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`, which is outside the range SQL expects.)

### References:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/482419-convert-todatetime-vs-system-datetime-parse

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jamie Not a problem - glad I could assist you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
DateTime.Parse("2015-06-16 09:17:28 PM");
```

And

```
Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

will return the same DateTime value.

I would try to focus on the query.

Note that you might be passing a value from C# that resolve in the minimum value for DateTime (1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM) which is out of range for DateTime value on SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Already solved the problem. I added  DateTime temp = DateTime.Parse(time); and it worked!

Comment: @AlbertMori That is not true. `Convert.ToDateTime(s)` calls `DateTime.Parse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.None)`. That last part is very important - whitespaces will do strange things. `DateTime.Parse(s)` uses `DateTime.Parse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces)`.

Comment: You are correct @EBrown, however given the string above this unit test passes without issues.        [TestMethod]
        public void DateTimeTest()
        {
            var date = "2015-06-16 09:17:28 PM";

            var data = DateTime.Parse(date);

            var data2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

            Assert.IsTrue(data == data2);
        }

Comment: @AlbertMori Regardless of the Unit Test, changing `Convert.ToDateTime` to `DateTime.Parse` worked for the OP. Perhaps there is something else in there we know not of.